# Placing an ellipse on a canvas programmatically on a Windows 8 store app

Tags: c#, xaml, canvas, shapes, ellipse

I've been successful at placing an ellipse on a canvas, but it shows up at the top left corner of it despite my trying different methods of moving it. In this attempt, I am trying to move it to the center of the canvas, but I would like to be able to move it anywhere in the canvas.

```
private Ellipse drawEllipse(Canvas aCanvas)
{
   Ellipse newEllipse= new Ellipse();
   newEllipse.Width = 40;
   newEllipse.Height = 40;
   newEllipse.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Aquamarine);
   aCanvas.Children.Add(lEllipse);
   newEllipse.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, aCanvas.ActualWidth / 2.0);
   newEllipse.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, aCanvas.ActualHeight / 2.0);

   return newEllipse;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Canvas.SetLeft(newEllipse, aCanvas.ActualWidth/2.0);
Canvas.SetTop(newEllipse, aCanvas.ActualHeight/2.0);
```

I didn't try it, but it worked for me all the time.

**Edit**: Ahh and you should probably first add the ellipse to the canvas before moving the ellipse around.